# Attach debugger to ASMX service on Azure app service

Tags: azure, debugging, visual-studio-2015, asmx

I have an old service that we have deployed up into Azure using an App Service (type: Web App). I publish this asmx direct from Visual Studio 2015 Professional. It works really well accept I cannot attach the VS 2015 Pro debugger to an instance of my ASMX.

I have set everything up correctly (so I think) in Azure and I am deploying with a `Debug` configuration:

[image]

But when I attach the debugger from VS - no errors are shown, it appears successful up until I set a new breakpoint, I get this (I have confirmed that I am attached to w3wp.exe):
[image]

I get a "hollow" breakpoint and the error:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

**I get what this error is, what I don't get is how can I successfully attach the debugger to an ASMX service on azure?**

Is attaching a debugger to ASMX on azure not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Despite everything **looking** like it was attached, it wasn't. I had to go to Debug > Attach to Process > and specify the website.

Using the remote debugging option on both Cloud Explorer and Server Explorer does not work in my scenario.

For a better walk through:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434211(v=vs.100).aspx

---

**The real issue:**
Azure does not play nice with < .net 4 
After upgrading the package to 4.5.2 I could do the following:

- Attach the debugger from VS
- Use the ConfigurationManager class to get application settings and connections strings from Azure
- Plus a few other basic Azure features.

Bottom-line, update .net before publishing

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours.